# How to upload a cloned git repository to an own git repository on github?

Tags: git, github, repository, push, clone

I have cloned a project from github. Now I want to upload it to my own private repository on github to work on it. But the cloned repository has in the origin key the value of the cloned project. What's the best practice to upload this project to my own private repository? I've read the german version of the git documentation (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) but haven't found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the command

```
git remote add newrepo NewRepoURL
```

you will have an additional remote called `newrepo` (you can name it any way you want) pointed to NewRepoURL. To **push** (not *upload*) you branch to the new remote do

```
git push newrepo master
```

Comment: I've got an error. I only have a README.md in my repo.
`$ git push myrep master
To https://github.com/xxxx/myrep.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/myrep.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do+not+have+locally%22

Answer (score 5):

Here the steps you can follow

```
git remote -v
git remote remove origin
git remote -v   //to check if it was remove
```

Go to Github, create a new repository.

```
git remote add origin <the new repository>
git remote -v
```

Comment: What do you mean by my repository? do you already have a repository you have created, and is it connected to some other project? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes. I'd created a repository and it is only my private repository. My intention was to build a website. For that I've created a private repository. Then I cloned google's website starter kit to have a clean and performant basic. Now I solved it this way: I initialized my directory to a git repo. After that I crested my files. Then I created a new branch in which I cloned Google's repo. After that I merged it to master branch and pushed it to GitHub. Thank you very much for your help.